# Want to make an action

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have an django site for new articles , in which multiple user write articles. 
I want to make an action for selecting a user , so that If I choose a particular user , I can only see its updation/insertion in admin site.

Answer (score 0):

If updation/insertion is part of a model that has an foreign key to USER model, then just write an admin-inlline to show a list of them in the user page below all other fields

Comment: I can do that, But cant I made a option bar to select user.

Comment: select user where ?
PLS provide some code or understandable design :)

Comment: suppose I have a table level. When I click on level in django I can see multipl level  and in every level there is a field "User" .A particular user can have more then one level. So I want to give an option bar in which we can choose user and for that user I can show levels. .